# SET STATISTICS IO not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I'm reading about query plans and I came across `SET STATISTICS`.

I'm using sql server 2012 express and I tried this simple code::

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT * from Sales.Customers
GO
```

Every article on the planet says I should be getting information about query execution time, but all I'm getting are the ACTUAL RESULTS of the select query. I can't find a single article about anyone having this same problem.

Comment: It's in a different tab - part of the message, not result set

Comment: **NO** with Statistics IO ON you won't see the time you will see the IO
related results ON the MEssage tab on SSMS,
IF you want to see just elapse and cpu time use 
    SET STATISTICS TIME ON

Answer (score 2):

Click on the messages tab to see statistics / print.

Click on Results to see the result set.

[image: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/i/b/newtab2.jpg]